# Area learning permission

Tags: google-project-tango

After EVERY build I get asked to permit Area Learning. It seems like the Core can't tell I've already given the permission to the very same app before, although the bundle id didn't change. It's one of those small things that become extremely annoying after a while. Could this be fixed and permission evaluated based on the bundle id? (using Unity)

Does anyone have a temporary workaround?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [adb](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html) to install your code onto the device while granting permissions automatically.

```
$ adb install -g <package>.apk
```

The g flag grants all the permissions from the manifest.

Comment: As mentioned, I'm using Unity so the apk gets installed by Unity on every build. Plus I don't think there are any Tango related permissions in the [Android specification](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html) at all. This is imo handled by the Tango Core app directly and that's where the weird behavior comes from.